# How to download an xml file in binary?

Tags: xml, download, webforms

I have a link called Download and he needs to download it in the browser of an XML file recorded in the database in binary format. What am I doing wrong?

Follows the code below:

```
 protected void DownloadFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int invoiceId = int.Parse((sender as LinkButton).CommandArgument);

        InvoiceManager iv = new InvoiceManager();
        Invoice invoice = iv.Find(invoiceId);
        if (invoice != null)
        {
            byte[] fileInBytes = invoice.FileContent;

            // Send the XML file to the web browser for download.
            Response.Clear();
            Response.Buffer = true;
            Response.ContentType = "text/xml";
            Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + invoice.FileName);
            Response.BinaryWrite(fileInBytes);
            Response.End();

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean that it displays in the browser instead of prompting a download, try changing your ContentType from text/xml to

```
protected void DownloadFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int invoiceId = int.Parse((sender as LinkButton).CommandArgument);

    InvoiceManager iv = new InvoiceManager();
    Invoice invoice = iv.Find(invoiceId);
    if (invoice != null)
    {
        byte[] fileInBytes = invoice.FileContent;

        // Send the XML file to the web browser for download.
        Response.Clear();
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + invoice.FileName);
        Response.BinaryWrite(fileInBytes);
        Response.End();

    }
}
```

That way you'll force the browser to prompt the file to be downloaded instead of trying to display it in the browser window.